# Why is the only the MathJax tutorial written by a user on Meta? Why not a dedicated page linked from math.SE?

Tags: discussion, support, mathjax

Shouldn't users, especially new users like me, have a prominent link explaining how to use MathJax on the front page of Math.SE?  Why is the only tutorial here: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

???

Comment: possible duplicate of [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's shown to everyone on the Ask Question page"

[image: How to format]

Also, nearly every existing question and answer has some math formatting, so its existence should suggest that something is going on here that's worth investigating...

Comment: Oh I never noticed that.  Thanks!  And good point.

Comment: 1) Most new users have no clue what MathJax is and the link is really not prominent (it is at the end) 2) What about users trying to post an answer? The tiny question mark is barely noticeable and has a wall of text before getting to latex. 3) The amount of questions posted by new users which don't use MathJax suggests doing something different than the current situation. (It might not work because the new posters don't really read anything like help/faq, but that is a different issue)